# how to print ajaxtoolkit pie chart(pdf form)?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i have code for printing normal piecharts using iTextSharp.dll (pdf generating lib)

namespaces used:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;
```

code:

```
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        PieChart1.SaveImage(stream, ChartImageFormat.Png);  //error line
        iTextSharp.text.Image chartImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(stream.GetBuffer());
        chartImage.ScalePercent(75f);
        pdfDoc.Add(chartImage);
        pdfDoc.Close();

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Chart.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
    }
```

But this code dosen't work for ajax pie charts, it show error:

> Error 1   'AjaxControlToolkit.PieChart' does not contain a definition for 'SaveImage' and no extension method 'SaveImage' accepting a first argument of type 'AjaxControlToolkit.PieChart' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

also is there any other way like printing piechart's div from javascript?
or any other code sample/reference?

Answer (score -1):

if you want to perform action from javascript. i would suggest you to use Highcharts it is best for all types of charts and also it gives builtin print and download as image or PDF.
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic
check this link and demo it is user friendly and light weight.